# AWS_PROFILE not working with aws cli

Tags: aws-cli

I have the aws cli installed on my macbook. I updated the version last week and since then it seems like it ignores the AWS_PROFILE environment variable? Has anyone encountered this? I have to add --profile to every statement now to make it go towards the profile I prefer.

Does anyone know what could be wrong or how I should troubleshoot it?

Comment: It is likely you have `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE` set which overrides `AWS_PROFILE`. Unset `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE` and try.

Comment: Sadly, same problem exists after unsetting that variable

Comment: I also have this problem. Trying to figure it out. Did you find a fix?

Comment: Not yet, I haven't used the CLI for a few days so I haven't had time to troubleshoot

Comment: I have the same issue. I had to specify `--profile` for every aws cli.

Comment: Also check for `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_KEY`, and `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` which will override `AWS_PROFILE`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was only setting the AWS_PROFILE as a shell variable and not as a environment variable. After setting is as an environment variable everything worked as expected.

Comment: I always set `AWS_PROFILE` as an env variable but still the same issue.

Answer (score 69):

As per this link: [AWS CLI environment variables Precedence](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html#id1)

> If AWS_PROFILE environment variable is set and the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY environment variables are set, then the credentials provided by AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY will override the credentials located in the profile provided by AWS_PROFILE.

You have to unset both `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and set `AWS_PROFILE` instead then it should work correctly.

```
unset AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
unset AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
export AWS_PROFILE=[profile-name-here]
```

Answer (score 16):

This looks like a bug to me.

Check my setup when I have nothing set for profile:

```
15278-gmcdaid:~ gmcdaid$ aws configure list
  Name                    Value             Type    Location
  ----                    -----             ----    --------
profile                <not set>             None    None
```

Now, set the env var:

```
15278-gmcdaid:~ gmcdaid$ export AWS_PROFILE=foo
```

Check setup again:

```
15278-gmcdaid:~ gmcdaid$ aws configure list
  Name                    Value             Type    Location
  ----                    -----             ----    --------
profile                  foo           manual    --profile
```

You can see that when AWS_PROFILE is set, the cli is set to use the manual switch for the profile, not the env var.

I installed the aws-cli around the same time you make this post.

Comment: Interesting, but it still sets the profile to foo, so it works for you anyway?

Comment: I opened an issue with the developers. Seems AWS_PROFILE is ignored if AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID are set. https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3304

Comment: Mine is working now :) I doublechecked my variables and I only set my variable as a shell variable and not as an environment variable. When I did that it started working

Comment: Still not working for me, with either Env of Shell vars. Could you provide any more detail or examples?

Comment: I didn't do much. I am using fish so I type: "set -xg AWS_PROFILE myprofile". Optionally use -U as well to set it everywhere. Then "env" displays the variable and aws configure list works as expected

Answer (score 5):

Just re-state in another words and clean commands:

Run `set | grep AWS`, if you see any credentials there then `AWS_PROFILE` will be ignored

If you set the variable just as

`AWS_PROFILE=boo`

it **won't work**. Export it instead:

`export AWS_PROFILE=boo`